# Running Thor in Rails production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

I want to run some thor task on rails 3 in production,
but I do not know how to set it up.
The following code did not work

```
class CheckData < Thor
  require File.expand_path('config/environment.rb')
end
```

Comment: are you gettin any error? if yes than what it is?

Comment: well,then the environment is development.i don't know how to change to production.and my goal is processing the production db by thor task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the RAILS_ENV environment variable to 'production' right above the`require`statement should work. I used conditional assignment here to default the environment to 'production' if the environment variable is not set ahead of time.

```
class CheckData < Thor
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
  require File.expand_path('config/environment.rb')
end
```

If you are running it as a Thor task from the command-line you can then set the environment variable before running and thus override the default assignment:

```
export RAILS_ENV=test; thor check_data
```

See Configuring Rails Applications [Rails Environment Settings](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-environment-settings) from [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) for more environment variables.